# How to optimize query with order by

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

Have query which generate OpenERP ORM. Table have 100k rows.

```
SELECT "tbl".id 
FROM "tbl" 
WHERE (("tbl"."active" = 'True')  AND  ("tbl"."is_company" IS NULL or "tbl"."is_company" = false )) 
ORDER BY "tbl"."display_name"
```

With indexes :

```
    "ix_tbl_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ix_active" btree (active)
    "ix_displayname" btree (display_name)
    "ix_iscompany" btree (is_company)
```

Query with order by takes 57735.775 ms.
Plan is :

```
 Sort  (cost=13031.73..13269.13 rows=94960 width=47) (actual time=57711.753..57725.079 rows=94967 loops=1)
   Sort Key: display_name
   Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 12918kB
   ->  Seq Scan on tbl (cost=0.00..5180.90 rows=94960 width=47) (actual time=0.009..57.056 rows=94967 loops=1)
         Filter: (active AND ((is_company IS NULL) OR (NOT is_company)))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 623
 Total runtime: 57735.775 ms
(7 rows)
```

When i try without order by it takes 65.969 ms.
Plan is :

```
 Seq Scan on tbl (cost=0.00..5180.90 rows=94960 width=4) (actual time=0.026..60.782 rows=94967 loops=1)
   Filter: (active AND ((is_company IS NULL) OR (NOT is_company)))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 623
 Total runtime: 65.969 ms
(4 rows)
```

With  `set enable_sort = off;` it takes  1206.157 ms plan is :

```
 Index Scan using ix_displayname on tbl(cost=0.00..21479.14 rows=94960 width=47) (actual time=29.912..1194.954 rows=94967 loops=1)
   Filter: (active AND ((is_company IS NULL) OR (NOT is_company)))
   Rows Removed by Filter: 623
 Total runtime: 1206.157 ms
(4 rows)
```

Any way to optimize it with indexes ? Because we cant change something in ORM .

Comment: Something is really wrong in that sort.  What sort of hardware are you on?  Also, what are you doing with 90+k rows?  Could you please include the table definition, too?

Comment: @dezso ORM use this query for sorting data. I just check slow querys and one of them is this. Field display_name  contains name and surnames

Comment: I'm simulating a similar scenario in one of my own tables with 100k rows of real data, and get the same results: fast with enable_sort = off, slow with on.

Comment: @ZiggyCrueltyfreeZeitgeister and did you find some solution ?

Comment: @GeoVIP no, but I didn't know about `enable_sort` before, and I'm sure it will come in handy for some of my own queries! It looks like _that_ is the solution, at least one that would be satisfactory to me.

Comment: Single columns indexes are not that useful, check all queries against this table and see if you can find composite indexes that match those predicates.

Comment: My guess is that the display names are in exactly descending order (or nearly) which is the worst possible case for quicksort.

Answer (score 0):

Using an index consisting of the columns `display_name`, `id`, `active` and `is_company` would enable the query to be run using the index alone.  Ordering the columns in the order provided would remove the sort requirement.  This comes at a slightly update cost, and could replace the `ix_displayname` index.

If `active` were rare, it would be faster to order the columns `active`, `display_name`, `id`, '`is_company`.  However, updating the `active` column would have higher update costs.

You may need to select the `display_name` in an inner query, or use an index hint.

Comment: An index hint? The question is tagged postgres.